# ¿Cómo hacer que se despliegue una lista de un menú?

Tags: css3

Me encuentro diseñando un menú y deseo saber que propiedad le puedo dar a una lista para que cuando se posicione el mouse por encima de su contenedor esta se muestre.

Por el momento esto es el resultado de lo que tengo momentáneamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver la lista se superpone al contenedor que la esta almacenando.

```
<nav class="menu">
                  <ul class="nivel1">
                     <li><a href="#">equipos de hogar</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">laptops</a></li>
                     <li><a class="desplegable">componentes<span class="icon-down-open"></span></a>
                        <ul class="submenu nivel2">
                           <li><a href="#">procesadores</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">tarjetas de video</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">motherboards</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">ram</a></li>
                           <li><a class="desplegable">almacenamiento<span class="icon-right-open cambioFlecha"></span></a>
                              <ul class="submenu nivel3">
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>ssd</b></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>hdd</b></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>externo</b></a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li><a href="#">case</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">fuentes de poder</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">enfriamiento</a></li>
                           <li><a class="desplegable">periféricos<span class="icon-right-open cambioFlecha"></span></a>
                              <ul class="submenu nivel3">
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>mouse</b></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>teclado</b></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>micrófono</b></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>parlantes</b></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"><b>headset</b></a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">monitores</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">impresoras</a></li>
                  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.menu {
   margin: auto;
   background: #000;
   color: #31B9DD;
   font-size: 0.7500em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
.menu ul {
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
}
.menu a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 0 15px;
   color: #31B9DD;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.menu a:hover {
   color: #CC3914;
}
.menu a span {
   margin-left: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.menu ul ul {
   display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   transform: translateY(-33px);
   top: auto;
}
.menu ul ul ul li{
   display: none;
}
.menu ul ul li:hover ul li {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
.submenu{
   display: none;
}
```

**¿Quisiera saber si hay forma de hacer que se visualice por la parte inferior del supuesto borde de abajo que tiene el menú?**

Ya que quitando la popiedad `transform: translateY(-33px)` de `.menu ul li:hover ul` si empieza al finalizar pero la sublista de nivel 3 igualmente empieza más abajo de lo que debería, como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue que ocupé la clase que se encuentra especificada en el `ul` que es .nivel3 y mediante el `css` omití la propiedad `transform: translateY(-33px);` de la clase .menu ul li:hover ul y la cambié a la antes mencionada.

```
.nivel3 {
   width: inherit;
   background: #4D5159;
   left: 100%;
   transform: translateY(-33px);
}
.menu {
   width: 90%;
   margin: auto;
   background: #000;
   font-size: 0.7500em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
.menu ul {
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
}
.menu a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #31B9DD;
   padding: 0 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.menu a i {
   margin-left: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.menu ul ul {
   display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: auto;
   top: initial;
}
.menu ul ul ul li {
   display: none;
   position: sticky;
}
.menu ul ul li:hover ul li{
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
```

el resultado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]